# How to I fix my code to only access one item in the list on each iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have been working with pygame for Python these past few days but I have encountered an issue that I can not seem to overcome. First let me talk about the issue and provide the code. The code with the issue is in the WIP branch of my repo. That is were new features are tested before been deployed.

https://github.com/Aeryes/Demented/blob/WIP/menu_testing.py

I have been trying to place my game menus in a class like structure to make it easier to create menus in the future by having a universal class for the menu creation. This has worked except for accessing individual members of my button list located in the menu class. When I check to see if a button is been hovered over to change color the check works but the new color is applied to all buttons in the list not just the one that is been hovered over.

I have tried many things thus far including the following:

1. I have tried to reference the individual item like this:

   --> main_menu.buttons[0].hovered = True

When I do this the code does not work nor does it break the program. It just makes no color change at all.

2. I have tried to remove the buttons = [] list from the Menu() class and create each button as an individual instance by doing the following:

   play_button = main_menu.add_button(button info here)

This just give me a NullType error when I call hovered = True.

I have been using this as a reference for help with this issue:
 https://python-forum.io/Thread-PyGame-Creating-a-state-machine

Here is my direct question: How do I get hovering to work for an individual button and not all of them at the same time?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if main_menu.buttons[0].rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            Button.hovered = True
        else:
            Button.hovered = False
```

You're not setting the hovered flag to true on the actual button, but rather the class (which, as far as I know, doesn't generally serve a function)

To correct it, you should be using

```
if main_menu.buttons[0].rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            main_menu.buttons[0].hover = True
        else:
            main_menu.buttons[0].hover = False
```

The bigger problem is that you never redraw your buttons after the update. The way I solved this (using your preexisting code) was to update your conditional to this:

```
if main_menu.buttons[0].rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            main_menu.buttons[0].hovered = True
            main_menu.buttons[0].draw()
        else:
            main_menu.buttons[0].hovered = False
            main_menu.buttons[0].draw()
```

There are a couple things to think about.

- A for loop iterating over indices would probably be much nicer than three individual conditionals.
- You have a bug in your menu class, where you write "for button in buttons:" instead of "for button in self.buttons:"
- Finally, you might want to look into your else condition. Given that you're currently recreating your menu continuously, it might not be necessary to un-hover the button, but I'll leave that to you

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. No button turns white.

Comment: Ok I've solved it, you have a few problems to fix. I was on the right track with my initial solution, I'll update it

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help really means a lot. Would you mind doing a pull request on the guthub branch for it ?

Comment: My solution code isn't complete nor very efficient, so I'll leave it to you to implement in a nicer manner. Let me know if my solution needs more explaining

Comment: Your solution works. I am going to mark it as best solution. Thank you for working with me on this. Means a lot.